# how to get specific background color in html canvas uisng javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, colors

i have a roulette made in html canvas using javascript, the roulette has rainbox color. the code is like below:

```js
var options = ["$100", "$10", "$25", "$250", "$30", "$1000"];

var startAngle = 0;
var arc = Math.PI / (options.length / 2);
var spinTimeout = null;

var spinArcStart = 10;
var spinTime = 0;
var spinTimeTotal = 0;

var ctx;

document.getElementById("spin").addEventListener("click", spin);

function byte2Hex(n) {
  var nybHexString = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  return String(nybHexString.substr((n >> 4) & 0x0F, 1)) + nybHexString.substr(n & 0x0F, 1);
}

function RGB2Color(r, g, b) {
  return '#' + byte2Hex(r) + byte2Hex(g) + byte2Hex(b);
}

function getColor(item, maxitem) {
  var phase = 0;
  var center = 128;
  var width = 127;
  var frequency = Math.PI * 2 / maxitem;

  red = Math.sin(frequency * item + 2 + phase) * width + center;
  green = Math.sin(frequency * item + 0 + phase) * width + center;
  blue = Math.sin(frequency * item + 4 + phase) * width + center;

  return RGB2Color(red, green, blue);
}

function drawRouletteWheel() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var outsideRadius = 200;
    var textRadius = 160;
    var insideRadius = 125;

    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;

    ctx.font = 'bold 12px Helvetica, Arial';

    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      var angle = startAngle + i * arc;
      //ctx.fillStyle = colors[i];
      ctx.fillStyle = getColor(i, options.length);

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(250, 250, outsideRadius, angle, angle + arc, false);
      ctx.arc(250, 250, insideRadius, angle + arc, angle, true);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.fill();

      ctx.save();
      ctx.shadowOffsetX = -1;
      ctx.shadowOffsetY = -1;
      ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
      ctx.shadowColor = "rgb(220,220,220)";
      ctx.fillStyle = "black";
      ctx.translate(250 + Math.cos(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius,
        250 + Math.sin(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius);
      ctx.rotate(angle + arc / 2 + Math.PI / 2);
      var text = options[i];
      ctx.fillText(text, -ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 0);
      ctx.restore();
    }

    //Arrow
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 4, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 9, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 0, 250 - (outsideRadius - 13));
    ctx.lineTo(250 - 9, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
    ctx.fill();
  }
}

function spin() {
  spinAngleStart = Math.random() * 10 + 10;
  spinTime = 0;
  spinTimeTotal = Math.random() * 3 + 4 * 1000;
  rotateWheel();
}

function rotateWheel() {
  spinTime += 30;
  if (spinTime >= spinTimeTotal) {
    stopRotateWheel();
    return;
  }
  var spinAngle = spinAngleStart - easeOut(spinTime, 0, spinAngleStart, spinTimeTotal);
  startAngle += (spinAngle * Math.PI / 180);
  drawRouletteWheel();
  spinTimeout = setTimeout('rotateWheel()', 30);
}

function stopRotateWheel() {
  clearTimeout(spinTimeout);
  var degrees = startAngle * 180 / Math.PI + 90;
  var arcd = arc * 180 / Math.PI;
  var index = Math.floor((360 - degrees % 360) / arcd);
  ctx.save();
  ctx.font = 'bold 30px Helvetica, Arial';
  var text = options[index]
  ctx.fillText(text, 250 - ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 250 + 10);
  ctx.restore();
}

function easeOut(t, b, c, d) {
  var ts = (t /= d) * t;
  var tc = ts * t;
  return b + c * (tc + -3 * ts + 3 * t);
}

drawRouletteWheel();
```

```html
<input type="button" value="SPIN" style="float:left;background:#A07F3D;color:white;margin-left:2%" id='spin' />
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

now the roulette is in rainbow color, instead i want to give this color #043F45 in canvas, the light and dark color of this color code in each box. can anyone please tell me how to accomplish this, thanks in advance

Comment: You said you made this, in other words, you programmed this. I would expect that you know where you apply the color in your code (as a hint: "you" wrote 2 functions specifically to return a color code)

Comment: If you take someone else code you have to credit that person (Barney Parker) which in this case is this CodePen: https://codepen.io/barney-parker/pen/OPyYqy

Comment: @tacoshy i didnt say anywhere i made this, please read the question properly

Comment: I am not clear exactly what coloring is wanted. Are alternate boxes to be colored differently or is each box to be colored the same, grading from light to dark versions of #043F45?

Comment: @AHaworth it should be like one box this color #043F45, and another box the lighter version of this color ,like chess box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getColor function now directly returns the light and dark shades of the specified color (#043F45) based on the item index. The shadeColor function is used to generate lighter and darker shades of the color.

```
function getColor(item, maxitem) {
    // Define the desired color
    var colorCode = "#043F45";

    // Calculate the light and dark shades of the color
    var lightColor = shadeColor(colorCode, 0.3);
    var darkColor = shadeColor(colorCode, -0.3);

    // Get the appropriate shade based on the item index
    var shade = item % 2 === 0 ? lightColor : darkColor;

    return shade;
}

// Function to generate lighter or darker shade of a given color
function shadeColor(color, percent) {
    var num = parseInt(color.slice(1), 16);
    var amt = Math.round(25.5 * percent); // Increased adjustment value from 2.55 to 25.5
    var R = (num >> 16) + amt;
    var G = (num >> 8 & 0x00FF) + amt;
    var B = (num & 0x0000FF) + amt;
    var newColor = "#" + (
      0x1000000 +
      (R < 255 ? (R < 1 ? 0 : R) : 255) * 0x10000 +
      (G < 255 ? (G < 1 ? 0 : G) : 255) * 0x100 +
      (B < 255 ? (B < 1 ? 0 : B) : 255)
    ).toString(16).slice(1);

    return newColor;
}
```

**The result after changes:**
[image: Increased amt]

Comment: i want to give light, dark versions of that particular color in each box

Comment: i tried it but it doesnt give the color, can u please show an example with the code in the question?

Comment: You should replace existing `getColor()` function with provided one and create new function `shadeColor()` that i provided. You can change contrast of the colors by increasing value in `amt` variable

Comment: i tried that, but its giving me black color

Comment: Try to copy and paste this code to your one. I edited above one and increased amt value. In my case it works properly.

Comment: thanks, how do i change the color of the numbers inside the box